The name ObjectFactory does not exist in the Current Context
it was working perfectly for .netFramework 4.6.2 and structureMap version was "2.6.4.1" Now after upgrading to .Net 8.0 version the version is changed to "4.7.1"
I am upgrading Target framework using Upgrade-assistant how to resolve this issue if I downgrade the version it wlll work but why in new version it is is giving this type error?
Error (active)  CS0103  The name 'ObjectFactory' does not exist in the current context

ObjectFactory was removed in an earlier version. You are going to have to implement your own or roll back to an earlier version.
